# Кодировка в сообщениях бота в тг

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Я пытаюсь вывести сообщение из файла в сообщения бота, но выводит в другой кодировке. Я пытался менять разрешения с HTML на txt и вообще без расширения.

Ввод:Фэнтези

Вывод:

```
Р—РІС‘Р·РґРЅР°СЏ РєРЅРёРіР° Р—РµРјР»Рё     РђРІС‚РѕСЂ:Р•Р»РµРЅР° РќРёРєРѕР»Р°РµРІРЅР° РЎРєРѕСЂРёРєРѕРІР°
```

```
        elif (p.normal_form == 'фэнтези'):
            with open("fentez", "r","utf-8") as file:
                lines = file.readlines()
                s=random.choice(lines)
                print(s)
                await message.reply(s)
```

Comment: Ничего не понял. В файле у вас слово Фентези, а выводит пару десятков символов?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так. Если это не поможет, то укажите кодировку вашего файла. Плюс не особо понимаю зачем вам выводить текст из html.

```py
with open("fentez.txt", "r", encoding='uft-8') as file:
```